# Retaining n most recent directories in a backup script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, backup

I have directory in `/home/backup/` that stores yearly backups. Inside the backup folder, we have these directories:

```
/home/backup/2012
/home/backup/2013
/home/backup/2014
/home/backup/2015
/home/backup/2016
/home/backup/2017
```

and every year I have to clean up the data, keeping only the last three years of backup.

In the above case, I have to delete:

```
/home/backup/2012
/home/backup/2013
/home/backup/2014
```

What is the best way to find the directories to be deleted?  I have this but it doesn't work:

```
find /home/ecentrix/recording/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -ctime +1095 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Do you guys have another idea to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your directories have well-defined and integer names, I'd just use bash to calculate the appropriate targets:

```
mkdir -p backup/201{2..7} # just for testing

cd backup
rm -fr $(seq 2012 $(( $(date +"%Y") - 3)))
```

`seq` generates a list of numbers from 2012 through the current year minus 3, which are then passed to `rm` to blast them.

Comment: your command line works perfectly! but how to add directory in your command? i need to add the command to cron job and my command line skills are not so good. sorry..

Comment: Change `cd backup` to `cd /full/path/to/your/backup/directory` and you are good to go. Alternatively, if your `seq` has the `-f` option, that would allow you to create file names with full paths.

Comment: this is the simplest and right command. i can refine it like `* * 1 1 * echo $(seq -f "/home/backup/%02g" 2012 $(( $(date +"%Y") - 3)))` to show full directory and add it to cronjob every year. it shows only backup directory, so it only delete the backup file directory only, not others. Thank you very much @bishop

Comment: This is reasonably elegant. Just remember any script has a chance at executing in unexpected ways. I always get nervous letting any script invoke a recursive delete. Please seriously consider setting the backups as belonging to a dedicated user and then invoking the pruning, as that same dedicated (and otherwise totally unprivileged) user.

Comment: I like this solution better than mine

Answer (score 5):

**A more generic solution**

I think it is best to traverse the directories in the descending order and then delete the ones after the third.  This way, there is no danger of losing a directory when the script is run again and again:

```
#!/bin/bash
backups_to_keep=3
count=0
cd /home/backup
while read -d '' -r dir; do
  [[ -d "$dir" ]]                || continue  # skip if not directory
  ((++count <= backups_to_keep)) && continue  # skip if we are within retaining territory
  echo "Removing old backup directory '$dir'" # it is good to log what was cleaned up
  echo rm -rf -- "$dir"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '[2-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' -type d -print0 | sort -nrz)
```

Remove the `echo` before `rm -rf` after testing.  For your example, it gives this output:

```
rm -rf -- ./2014
rm -rf -- ./2013
rm -rf -- ./2012
```

- `cd /home/backup` restricts `rm -rf` to just that directory for extra safety
- `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '[2-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' -type d` gives the top level directories that match the glob
- `sort -nrz` makes sure newer directories come first, `-z` processes the null terminated output of `find ... -print0`
- This solution doesn't hardcode the years - it just assumes that the directories to be removed are named in numerically sortable way
- It is resilient to any other files or directories being present in the backup directory
- There are no side effects if the script is run again and again
- This can easily be extended to support different naming conventions for the backup directory - just change the glob expression

Comment: nice solution and nice explanation.

Answer (score 4):

## Solution

```
# Check if extended globbing is on
shopt extglob

# If extended globbing is off, run this line
shopt -s extglob

# Remove all files except 2015, 2016, and 2017
rm -r -i /home/backup/!(2015|2016|2017)

# Turn off extended globbing (optional)
shop -u extglob
```

## Explanation

`shopt -s extglob` allows you to match any files except the ones inside `!(...)`. So that line means remove any file in `/home/backup` except `2015`, `2016`, or `2017`.

The `-i` flag in `rm -r -i ...` allows you to interactively confirm the removal of each file. Remove `-i` if you want the files to be removed automatically.

## Dynamic Dates

This solution is valid for automation (e.g. cron jobs)

```
# Number of latest years to keep
LATEST_YEARS=3

# Get the current year
current_year=$(date '+%Y')

# Get the first/earliest year to keep
first_year=$(( current_year - $(($LATEST_YEARS - 1)) ))

# Turn on extended globbing
shopt -s extglob

# Store years to keep in an array
keep_years=( $(seq $first_year $current_year) )

# Specify files to keep
rm -r /home/backup/!(${keep_years[0]}|${keep_years[1]}|${keep_years[2]})
```

> NOTE: ALL FILES IN BACKUP DIRECTORY WILL BE REMOVED EXCEPT LAST 3 YEARS

Comment: How would you add it to, say, crontab?

Comment: The OP did not mention they wanted it automated. Nevertheless, I'll oblige.

Comment: i already said that on the question @ShammelLee. I need to run it every year. So, I need to add it to cron job. Thank you vagoberto

Comment: @user1008497 your question does not mention that you need to run it in an automated fashion. Nevertheless, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Consider this:

```
find /home/backup/2* -maxdepth 1 | sort -r | awk "NR>3" | xargs rm -rf
```

### How this works

1. Produce a list of filenames starting with "2", only under */home/backup/*
2. Alphabetically sort the list, in reverse order.
3. Use AWK to filter the number of rows in the list. *NR* specifies the number of reverse-sorted rows. You can change that 3 to be however many rows you want to be left. So if you only wanted the latest two years, change the *3* to a *2*. If you wanted the latest 10 to be kept, make it *"NR>10"*.
4. Append the resultant list to the command "rm -rf".

### Run as dedicated user, for safety

The danger here is that I'm suggesting *rm -rf*. This is risky. If something goes wrong, you could delete things you want to keep. I mitigate this risk by only invoking these commands by a dedicated user that ONLY has permissions to delete backup files (and not beyond).

### Merit

The merit of this approach is that when you throw it in a cron job and time advances, it'll continue to retain only the latest few directories. So this, I consider to be a general solution to your problem.

### Demonstration

To test this, I created a test directory with all the same directories you have. I altered it just to see what would be executed at the end, so I've tried:

```
find test01/2* -maxdepth 1 | sort -r | awk "NR>4" | xargs echo rm -rf
```

*I used NR>4 rather than NR>3 (as you'd want) because NR>4 shows that we're selecting how many rows to remove from the list, and thus not delete.*

Here's what I get:
[image: Demonstration]

The second-to-final command above changed the final stage not to *echo* what it would do, but actually do it.

I have a crude copy of a dump of this in a script as I use it on some servers of mine, you can view it here: https://github.com/docdawning/teenybackup

### Required for success

This approach DEPENDS on the alphabetization of whatever the *find* command produces. In my case, I use [ISO-8601 type dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which lend themselves entirely to being inherently date-sorted when they're alphabetized. Your YYYY type dates totally qualify.

### Additional Safety

I recommend that you change your backups to be stored as tar archives. Then you can change the *rm -rf* to a simple *rm*. This is a lot safer, though not fool-proof. Regardless, you really should run this as a dedicated otherwise unprivileged user (as you should do for any script calling a delete, in my opinion).

Be aware that if you start it with

```
find /home/backup
```

Then the call to xargs will include /home/backup itself, which would be a disaster, because it'd get deleted too. So you must search within that path. Insteading calling it with the below would work:

```
find /home/backup/*
```

The 2* I gave above is just a way of somewhat limiting the search operation.

### Warranty

None; this is the Internet. Be careful. Test things heavily to convince yourself. Also, maybe get some offline backups too.

---

Finally - I previously posted this as an answer, but made the fatal mistake of representing the find command based out of */home/backup* and not */home/backup/** or */home/backup/2**. This caused */home/backup* to also be sent for deletion, which would be a disaster. It's a very small distinction that I've tried to be clear about above. I've deleted that previous answer and replaced it with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

Updated answer.

```
[dev]$ find backup/*  | grep -vE "$(date '+%Y')|$(date +%Y --date='1 year ago')|$(date +%Y --date='2 year ago')" | xargs  rm -rfv

removed directory: ‘backup/2012’
removed directory: ‘backup/2013’
removed directory: ‘backup/2014’
```